# Same username with custom and facebook login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, single-sign-on

I've a site with user registration (ASP.Net Membership) and Facebook login button.

I use `SetAuthCookie(model.UserName...` in both login acions and everithing seems to work!

Now... what if a FB username is the same of already registered user?

Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my site, when there is a conflict between existing username and upcoming user's facebook username, in that case at final stage of registration we ask to just enter username and then continue to application.

Answer (score 0):

Store the username and facebook username in different fields.

When the user logs in ask them to select a login method - that will tell you whether to use FB or Username.

Often it's a good idea to use an email address as a username - since that will (generally) be linked to a single person - i.e. you wouldn't have multiple users sharing the same email address (unless maybe they're a couple who share an account - but they can then work out a solution between themselves).